# Import Failing on Truncation, Even With Ignore on Truncate Set

Tags: sql-server, import

I am importing a huge csv file into SQL Server using Import Wizard.  In the Review Data Type Mapping section, all columns are set to "use glocal" for error and truncation.  The globals for both are set to ignore.  Despite this, the process errors out.  Whn I look at the error report, I see:

> "The data conversion for column "[col]" returned
>   status value 4 and status text "**Text was truncated or one or more
>   characters had no match in the target code page.**"

The column data type is set to nvarchar(255) so it should handle unicode.  If the column length is not long enough, it should not be failing, as I specifically set it to ignore truncation.

What's going on here???
.

Comment: Same issue here, using SQL 2017 and SSMS 17.